# Apple says I'm signing an app with old OS version, and I'm not

Tags: java, apple-store, code-signing

I'm trying to submit a Java-based app to AppStore. After having the worst headaches in my life trying to sign everything my last problem (I hope!) is this:

> Invalid code signature - Signatures created with OS X version 10.8.5
>   or earlier [v1 signatures] are obsoleted and will no longer be
>   recognized by Gatekeeper beginning with OS X version 10.9.5. To ensure
>   your apps will run on updated versions of OS X they must be signed on
>   OS X version 10.9 or later [v2 signatures]. For more information, see
>   OS X Code Signing In Depth

I don't understand this message because:

1) I'm running a 10.10.1 version

```
$ sw_vers -productVersion 
10.10.1
```

2) and my app is signed with version 2 signatures

```
$ codesign -dv MyApp.app
Executable=/Users/jess/git/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaAppLauncher
Identifier=com.myapp
Format=bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20200 size=286 flags=0x0(none) hashes=5+5 location=embedded
Signature size=4351
Signed Time=20/2/2015 16:31:42
Info.plist entries=20
TeamIdentifier=D38HW9S49C
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=12 files=15
Internal requirements count=1 size=204
```

(You can see the line saying **Sealed Resources version=2 rules=12 files=15**)

So, what is the problem ? What am I missing ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I found it ... I know this answer seems crazy, but it's the solution.

When you bundle the app, the folder *YourApp.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.{your_version}.jdk/Contents/*  dissapears, so you have just to recover it from the JDK home, and the bundle "will looks fine" to Apple.

So:

```
cp -r /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.{your_version}/Contents/MacOS YourApp.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk{your_version}.jdk/Contents/
```

And it's working !

Thank you Apple for a message so clear :-P

Comment: I would think the real way of making sure that the directory is copied is to make sure it is included in a Copy ... build phase